# Is is it possible to load play! WS in ammonite REPL?

Tags: web-services, playframework

Is there a way to load `play.api.libs.ws.WS` in the [ammonite REPL](http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the following two lines into the REPL:

```
load.ivy("com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.4.6")
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
```

The first loads the dependency while the second actually imports it.